# Calculating occupany level between a date range

Tags: oracle11g, count, date-range

I'm having trouble trying to wrap my head around how to write this query to calculate the occupancy level of a hotel and then list the results by date. Consider the following type of data from a table called reservations:

```
Arrival     Departure    Guest    Confirmation
08/01/2015  08/05/2015   John     13234
08/01/2015  08/03/2015   Bob      34244
08/02/2015  08/03/2015   Steve    32423
08/02/2015  08/02/2015   Mark     32411
08/02/2015  08/04/2014   Jenny    24422
```

Output Data would ideally look like:

```
Date        Occupancy
08/01/2015  2
08/02/2015  4
08/03/2015  2
08/04/2015  1
08/02/2015  0
```

And the query should be able to utilize a date range as a variable. I'm having trouble getting the obviously hardest piece of how to both get the count per night and spitting it out by date.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a list of dates first. In Oracle you can do this by using `connect by`. This will make a recursive query. For instance, to get the next 30 days, you can select today and keep connecting until you've got the desired number of days. `level` indicates the level of recursion.

```
select trunc(sysdate) + level - 1 as THEDATE 
from dual
connect by level <= 30;
```

On that list, you can query the number of reservations for each day in that period:

```
select THEDATE,
       (select count(*)
        from reservations r
        where r.Arrival >= THEDATE and
              r.Departure < THEDATE) as RESERVATIONCOUNT
from  
  ( select trunc(sysdate) + level - 1 as THEDATE,
    from dual
    connect by level <= 30)
```

Instead of getting a fixed number of dates, you can also get another value there, for instance, to get *at least* 30 days in the future, but further if there are reservations for later..:

```
select THEDATE,
       (select count(*)
        from reservations r
        where r.Arrival >= THEDATE and
              r.Departure < THEDATE) as RESERVATIONCOUNT
from  
  ( select trunc(sysdate) + level - 1 as THEDATE,
    from dual
    connect by 
      level <= greatest(30, (select trunc(max(DEPARTURE) - sysdate)
                             from reservations)))
```